# Spring Boot API CPU not returning to idle levels when handling errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heap-memory

I have a Sprint Boot API application which has been experiencing slowdown once a month or so. The only way to rectify this is to restart the application.

Investigation into metrics and usage of API helped us figure out that spamming HTTP requests to a specific controller which would lead to exception being thrown causes the CPU utilization not to return to normal. The CPU util hovers between 25-35% consistently when the requests are spammed. The exact steps to reproduce are:

1. Execute a bash script with infinite loop to send HTTP requests which throw an exception (run multiple instances)
2. Wait till server has reached 100% cpu util
3. Wait 15 minutes
4. Stop infinite loop in bash script

Using Java Visual, we can see the cpu util hovering around 25% when the HTTP requests stop:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ7Yr.png)

We have tried multiple things such as upgrading the spring boot version, setting the system variable LatencyUtils.useActualTime to false, performing garbage collection.

When we look at the heap histogram, we can see the class with highest instances is io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag[]:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCv92.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

CPU util/memory going back to idle levels when the application isn't receiving any requests

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can use one heapdump as baseline, then compare to get which instances increased. after look at the image you post, maybe traceid used as metrics tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of cases where CPU utilization is consistent -

1. check the db connection pool size
2. any executor service that is used not close after use
3. any thread pool executor services sed - check core threads